# Add image to push notifications using AMPscript

Tags: ampscript, mobilepush, push

We want to add an image to our push notifications using AMPscript and want to know if that is possible in the marketing cloud?

I have read through this document: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/image.htm but don't know how to proceed from here.